# Importing XML with 'µ' symbol into excel

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, excel

I am trying to import an XML file into excel using Data -> Other Sources -> From XML Data import. When the file contains a 'µ' symbol, it gives the following error:

> Invalid file reference. The path to the file is invalid, or one or
>   more of the referenced schemas could not be found.

The XML looks like this:

```
<root>
  <File>
    <FileName>Data\7.5 µg_mL Sample.pdf</FileName>
  </File>
</root>
```

If i remove the microgram symbol, it works and Excel imports the data.

I am generating the XML file in .net using `XNode.toString()`, and if I run the XML through a validator, it returns no errors. It doesn't seem to matter if I put the XML declaration at the top of the file and declare it as UTF-8 or 16 either.

Any pointers welcome, i would ideally like to check for any characters that might cause this problem as i am guessing there are more than just the microgram symbol.

I am passing the XML string to a function that swaps out a custom xml file, i don't seem to have the option to change the file format here..

```
'Uses Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(fileDest)
    zip.RemoveEntry(xmlPath)
    zip.Save()
    zip.AddEntry(xmlPath, customXml)
    zip.Save()
End Using
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates this file? I did a quick test, if you save that file as ANSI encoded then you get the error. If you save as UTF-8, it seems to work fine. I'd assume the first is guessed as UTF-8 with no BOM and fails on the invalid character.

Comment: Why don't you use `XDocument.Save` with an `XmlWriter` that has in its Settings the encoding set to UTF8? That is somewhat similar to what @CharlesMager points out.

Comment: I'm using Ionic.Zip.ZipFile to remove an xml file in a zip file and replace it with a new one, i'll pop that code in the bottom of the post now

Comment: If you start `notepad.exe`, then choose "Open", the in the "Open" dialog navigate to the XML file in question without actually leaving the "Open" dialog window, what "Encoding" is suggested in the bottom of the window? You can also ask Visual Studio ("File - Advanced Save Options" when the XML file has been opened).

Comment: Aha, i _can_ pass the encoding as a parameter!

Comment: @CharlesMager as you were first in there, pop up an answer and i will give it to you!

Comment: Also note that there are two different Unicode code points, the usual Greek letter is U+03BC (μ), however, for historical reasons, there is also U+00B5 (µ) which has been part of Latin 1 (and the related `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/22d20868-e8bf-555a-10e7-f6e7cada6826.htm) for the overload of `AddEntry` you are using:

> The content for the entry is encoded using the default text encoding for the machine

You want this to be UTF-8, so you can use [the overload that allows you to specify the encoding](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/b3e73579-6685-a8e2-4e2c-193553e84a9a.htm):

```
zip.AddEntry(xmlPath, customXml, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Spot on, just got there a min before you posted! :) no idea why my intellisense wasn't showing that overload